# Want to know about permission handling for marshmallow

Tags: android

In marshmallow how to handle the permission? How to avoid user interaction for requesting and handling permission. How to request and handle permission for location?

Comment: You cannot avoid requesting the permission on Marshmallow. Refer to this page: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In marshmallow for permission user interaction is required,you can ask for all required permission at the time of app launches. It will be only once but also make sure whenever you try to access location to check permission using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` as user can revoke app permission anytime.

Comment: But in my project I want to send location automatically, how can I do this in marshmallow?

Comment: Want to store the value of radio button into sqlite. In my project I have 3 radio buttons General Silent and vibrate, now I want to store the status of each radio button or radio button which has been selected into sqlite.

Comment: If you just want to store selected radio button value i will suggest to use SharedPreference. e.g. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharedpreferenceseditor-for-radiobutton.html

Comment: But I want to store in sqlite database, where user may have multiple entries and may be one entry contain silent where as another contain general. Each time values may be different. Then how can I use sharedpreference to store multiple values in database